# SQL PROFILER Replay statistics event interpretation

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2016, profiler

I tried capturing a replayable trace on a SQL Server 2012  production environment and then replay it against a SQL 2016 test environment.

After doing so , I got the following results :

[image]

Can  anyone help me identify what each of the below highlighted term represents :

- Total events = 89
- Replayed events = 39
- Provider errors = 13
- Internal    errors = 26
- Total errors = 39
- Provider hit ratio = 66.67 %
- Internal    hit ratio = 33.33 %
- Overall hit ratio = 0.00 %
- Replay time = 0 hr 2 min 12 sec 38 ms

Will be of great help as I am not able to understand how the upgrade to 2016 might perform based on the profiler results.

Answer (score 1):

I am afraid this replay will not help you at all. It will not give you any indication about performance in your new test server as all the replay events failed.

I recommend you read [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sql-server-profiler/replay-requirements?view=sql-server-2017#data-columns-required-for-replay) when you take your trace at source, especially following sections:

[Event Classes Required for Replay](http://Event%20Classes%20Required%20for%20Replay)

[Data Columns Required for Replay](http://Data%20Columns%20Required%20for%20Replay)

I will use these terms so I do not repeat the same thing:

SQL Server 2012 production environment = Source

SQL 2016 test environment = Destination

- Total events = Number of events that was captured from source
- Replayed events = Number of events replayed at destination
- Provider errors = Look at the `textdata` column for details on each `provider warnings or error`
- Internal errors = Look at `Errors and Warnings` column for details
- Total errors = Sum(Provider errors + Internal errors)
- Provider hit ratio = Ration between `Replayed events` and `Providers errors`
- Internal hit ratio = Ration between `Replayed events` and `Internal errors`
- Overall hit ratio = Meaning out of 39 `Replayed events` all of those timed out either and `Provide errors` or `Internal error`. In your case it 13+26=39.
- Replay time = Time took to replay trace at destination.

You can load your test result into a table and then you should be easily able find details about errors. As an example for `Provider Errors` you can use following query which I copied from [this](http://www.biadmin.com/2012/06/sql-2012-upgrade-part-5-query-playback.html) blog post.

```
SELECT RowNumber,
       EventClass,
       TextData,
       ConnectionID,
       SPID,
       EventSubclass,
       RequestProperties,
       RequestParameters,
       BinaryData
  FROM dbo.Trace_Replay_Results
 WHERE EventClass = 63485
```

Comment: Hi ! Thanks for the answer! Will try the above.

Comment: If this answers your question please mark it as accepted so other users can be benefited.